# Possible to pass WPF form by interface?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, forms, interface, args

I know I have done this with Winforms and thought I had done it with WPF forms but it doesn't seem to be working for me now.

AKA...I love MVVM but sometimes I just want to throw up a prompt in the middle of my Viewmodel logic.  In those cases I ask the View to pass me a prompt just in case I need it.  The Prompt Implements an interface with the simple methods and properties I need (ex: ShowDialog, DialogResult etc...).  I have also used Events to throw the duty back to the UI to prompt but sometimes it just seems cleaner for the VM to prompt without knowing what the view is via an interface.

So, did something change with WPF forms or I am just mistaken.  I get a "Value of type 'PTO_DayDetail()' cannot be converted to 'iBasicPrompt'" build error when trying to pass a Form that Implements iBasicPrompt to a method expecting iBasicPrompt.

```
Public Class PTO_DayDetail
    Implements MBS.Core.Interfaces.iBasicPrompt
End Class
```

Public Sub Add(... Prompt As MBS.Core.Interfaces.iBasicPrompt)

Comment: I've done an interface with a WPF content control with no issue.  In that case, I accessed it as (screen).Content and used TryCast to coerce to my interface.

Comment: I often use a control in the view and binding. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Getting_Confirmation

Comment: You should be able to have your Window class implement an interface and pass it as that interface type without a problem. Maybe post a bit more of your code? I can't spot a mistake yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I did something wrong (not sure what as I went a different route).  I built a test app to post here and it all worked fine.  Hmmmm.  Weird.

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I didn't have a argless constructor on the form.  My name is George.  Which way did he go.  Which way did he go  :)